# Multitouch in mobile browsers

Tags: android, iphone, browser, mobile, multi-touch

Can anyone elaborate on what mobile browsers support multitouch, in particular the ability to press multiple "buttons" (or joysticks) at the same time? It is required for a game I'm making and would like to know, so I can switch to native app instead if necessary, though prefer not to.

If the answer is, it is generally not supported, does anyone happen to know a library/framework which can create screens from XML format or similar, like HTML, cross platform-wise and cross resolution-wise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Multitouch is supported on Honeycomb and higher, and iOS 4 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get coordinates of 3 touch
function touch(e){
    var touch1 = {x:e.changedTouches[0].clientX,y:e.changedTouches[0]};
    var touch2 = {x:e.changedTouches[1].clientX,y:e.changedTouches[1]};
    var touch3 = {x:e.changedTouches[2].clientX,y:e.changedTouches[2]};
}
```

you can get coordinates of each touch flowing up.